# Laravel virtual server routing doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have installed newest Laravel on my Apache2. I run in Terminal

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

And It works. I have sub-pages and everything I need. But I want to have access without run this command.

I have next mylaravel.com.conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mylaravel.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mylaravel/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My Laravel files is of course in `/var/www/mylaravel`. In this configuration mylaravel.com works, but when I try for simple `mylaravel.com/auth/register` Apache return

[image]

When I used php artisan [...] this works fine. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem a while ago. From [here](http://www.epigroove.com/blog/laravel-routes-not-working-make-sure-htaccess-is-working):

> If you don't have AllowOverride set to All, your Laravel .htaccess file (/public/.htaccess) won't be able to enable mod_rewrite, and your routes won't work.

Try adding the following to your `<VirtualHost>` block:

```
<Directory "/var/www/mylaravel/public">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

So all up you'd have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mylaravel.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mylaravel/public

    <Directory "/var/www/mylaravel/public">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The error he's getting is "404 Not Found", not "403 Forbidden".

Comment: @ghoti I know. This solution worked for me, so maybe it'll help the OP as well.

Comment: Do you know *why* the solution worked for you?  Is there perhaps a .htaccess in laravel's documentroot that forces all requests through a single PHP script? I don't know anything about Larevel, but I do know that when you make server configuration changes, they should not be accidental.  Perhaps including a link to the [relevant Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#pretty-urls) might improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found something. I added Sadurnias code and run in Terminal

sudo a2enmod rewrite
   sudo service apache2 restart

Of course I changed chmod of /var/www to 755.

It's working fine, only when I run mylaravel.com/css FireFox doesn't end this request, but others is fine.